# GNUPLOT: invalid expression?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnuplot

I have a simple gnuplot script that plots a bunch of graphs. When I run it, it gives the following error:

EDIT: I've reduced the length of the code considerably as per the suggestions

```
    ;
    set xrange [pe_cnt:range_high];
    set xtics xticks;
    set xtics add (pe_cnt) 
                                                                                 ^
line 26: invalid expression
```

I've spent a lot of time in trying to solve this. I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me on this. This is my code:

```
range_high="`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="--stop") print $(i+1)}' temp_info`"
xticks="`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="--xticks") print $(i+1)}' temp_info`"
pe_cnt = "`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="--pe_cnt") print $(i+1)}' temp_info`"
rd_cnt = "`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="--rd_cnt") print $(i+1)}' temp_info`"


##################################################################################################
# Gnuplot script file for plotting Micron >= 1,16,32,64 WAFL single read last read


set autoscale    
set grid         
set title "Usable Flash Blocks vs PE cycles"

set xlabel "PE Cycles  "
set ylabel "% Usable Flash Blocks "
set y2label "% WAFL Blocks"

if (pe_cnt == range_high) {
    set xrange [pe_cnt-1:range_high]
    set xtics xticks
    set xtics add (pe_cnt-1) }
else { 
    set xrange [pe_cnt:range_high]
    set xtics xticks
    set xtics add (pe_cnt) }

set yrange [-10:140]
set y2range [-10:140]

set ytics 10
set y2tics 10

set term postscript color solid
set output 'Micron_srd.ps'

#set datafile separator ' '

set key top left
plot "Micron_all"      using (($1+1)*pe_cnt):(((256-$31)*100)/256)  smooth bezier  title '(>= 1 Bad WAFL)'      axis x1y1 with lines, \
     "Micron_all"      using (($1+1)*pe_cnt):(((256-$33)*100)/256)  smooth bezier  title '(>= 16 Bad WAFL)'      axis x1y1 with lines, \
     "Micron_all"      using (($1+1)*pe_cnt):(((256-$34)*100)/256)  smooth bezier  title '(>= 32 Bad WAFL)'      axis x1y1 with lines, \
     "Micron_all"      using (($1+1)*pe_cnt):(((256-$36)*100)/256)  smooth bezier  title '(>= 64 Bad WAFL)'      axis x1y1 with lines, \
     "Micron_all"      using (($1+1)*pe_cnt):(($14*400)/$5)  smooth bezier  title '(Uncorrectable WAFL)'      axis x1y2 with lines, \
     "Micron_all"      using (($1+1)*pe_cnt):(($70*100)/$5)  smooth bezier  title '(Correctable WAFL)'      axis x1y2 with lines
```

Comment: Could you please make a [small, self-contained example](http://www.sscce.org)? It will make it much easier to figure out what the problem is, both for others and for yourself.

Comment: @that_other_guy I've reduced the code, but I'm still getting the same error. I've no idea why this is happening. I have another script that is identical to this one but that works.

Comment: OK so the error goes away when i comment the line "set xtics add (pe_cnt)" but can anyone tell me why I am getting the error? I've checked and the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
set xtics add (real(pe_cnt))
```

I guess, `xtics add` does not automatically cast a string to a number, because it allows also a different syntax when a string is encountered first.
The following does the cast:

```
set xtics add (pe_cnt pe_cnt)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that `pe_cnt` is not a number, but your test case is not self contained (it reads this value from some file), so it's hard to be specific.

Here is a short, self-contained example that demonstrates the same error message with the same code:

```
pe_cnt = "kittens"
set xtics add (pe_cnt)
```